# Chrome-Extension:How to pass a imageData from content script to the background without losing its data

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension

I'm doing a test.It's gonna be constantly passing the updated imageData to the background page and everything runs well,but the data posted will not be imageData.I'm stuck here.

```
contentscript.js:
var Data=context.getImageData(0,0,canvas.width,canvas.height)
port.postMessage(Data)


background.js:
var Data
chrome.extension.onConnect.addListener(function(port)
{
    port.onMessage.addListener(function(msg) {
        Data=msg
    })
})
```

The imageData will end up being a object,which is nonsense.
Could you please help me?
[This is what the imageData will be](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OTtye.png)

Comment: It's [documented](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/messaging) and you can find many similar answered questions here: the data should be JSON-serializable, which the imageData is not. Convert it to a data url or work with canvas in the background page script.

Comment: Excuse me, what do you mean to work with canvas in the background page script?

Comment: Background page has DOM just like any other web page and you can work with canvas there.

Comment: Thank you,I'm going to convert the datas to data url now.What if I still want to pass the imageData,then how to make it possible to work with the canvas in the background?The datas will be invalid......

Comment: Well, if your canvas loads an image from the web page and you'd like to do it in a background page, I think you'd have to fetch the image once again with XMLHttpRequest.

Comment: The imageData is from the video and being brawn with canvas.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/934012/get-image-data-in-javascript